# How do I get label value as a parameter into a javascript function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, html, data-binding

Hopefully this one is not too hard to understand but I just want the label values to be inputs into a javascript function. Might be better to explain with code:

ASP.NET Label code:

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelCL" runat="server" Text="A single int filled in by DB"></asp:Label>
```

Page Source:

```
<span id="ctl00_cpMainContent_LabelCL">7</span>
```

What I would like to achieve but am not sure how to do:

```
<span id="ctl00_cpMainContent_LabelCL">     <script type="text/javascript">functionX(7)</script>    </span>
```

So basically just wrap the output int in the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">functionX( VALUE FROM LABEL TEXT)</script>
```

within the
 `<span></span>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelCL" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var value = document.getElementById("<%= LabelCL.ClientID %>").innerHTML;
    functionX(value);
</script>
```

If it is called just after render you can simply use `LabelCL.Text`, if you need the value after and if it can be edited you can do as the exemple above.

With jQuery you can use

```
$("[id$=LabelCL]")
```

to retrieve the element.

Comment: Where does the ".ClientID" come from?

Comment: It is a property of the control, it is the ID which will be rendered on the page, to the final element (html element). `<%= LabelCL.ClientID %>` means get the control `LabelCL` and return it's ClientID

Answer (score 2):

```
var span = document.getElementById('ctl00_cpMainContent_LabelCL'),
    text = span.firstChild;

functionX(text.textContent);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YVdjb/1/)**

or if defined in the Page use script tags to render out the client id for the span using

```
<%= LabelCL.ClientID %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelCL" runat="server" Text="A single int"></asp:Label>
<button onclick="displayContent(<%= LabelCL.ClientID %>)">click me</button>
<script>
    function displayContent(obj) {
        alert(obj.innerText);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="<script type='text/javascript'>document.write(functionX(7));</script>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this piece of code

```
onclick="myFunction(labelName.innerText)"
```

Comment: This is lacking an explanation